# Set window selection from a previously saved selection object

Tags: javascript, dom, range, selection

If I have a selection object from a textarea (with a class of my-text-area) using `window.getSelection()`, if this selection loses focus (say if the user clicks on another input field), is there a way I can set this selection again programmatically?

I've tried doing something like this:

When I have focus:

```
var currentSelection = window.getSelection();
```

After I lose focus and want to set the selection again:

```
var range = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
range.selectNode($('.my-text-area')[0]);

var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();

sel.addRange(range);
```

This seems to select everything in my textarea though, not just the small selected area initially.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the excellent Rangy library, that contains a Selection Save and Restore module that does exactly this: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Selection-Save-Restore-Module